# Manga featuring a male main character who is weak but thought to be strong, and a princess, a priestess, and a sorceress

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic

I’m looking for a black and white manga about a male main character (MC) who is weak but thought to be strong by other people.

There are three main female characters: a princess, a priestess, and a sorceress. The princess and priestess both believe the MC is powerful but the witch does not.

Things happen in the story that are accidents or not his fault, but the princess thinks he is always the one doing it, which is why she believes he's strong.

He also has a tiger beast woman that converts to protecting him after she defects from the demon lord's side.

There is also a child that the MC saves who was evil but gets purified by the MC.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: Mostly black and white

Comment: Why do other characters think the MC is strong if he's not?

Comment: Things happen in the story that makes it look as if the mc did it but it was an accident or not his fault but the Princess thinks he is always the one doing it.

Comment: I also just remembered that the three main females are the princess, a priestess, and a sorceress. The priestess also believes that the mc is powerful but the witch does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this ***[The Good Deeds of Old Adventurer Kane](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-good-deeds-of-old-adventurer-kane)***...?

> Meet Kane: a D-rank adventurer with nothing going for him but his kindness. He's spent the last 20 years getting by with herb-picking requests, but one day, he comes across a super rare item: The Fruit of Revival! Giving it away for not much more than pocket change, little does he know that his life is about to change...
>
> [image: Prmotional art for "The Good Deeds of Old Adventurer Kane."]

As noted in the summary above, the protagonist, Kane, is a veteran D-rank adventurer who spent the last 20 years fulfilling medicinal herb fetch quests.

Through a combination of luck and his own kindness, he ends up receiving an invitation request from an S-rank party of adventurers comprised of the "Godspeed Sword Princess," Anastoria Armillion, the "Pure Saint," Sephiria Clement, and the "Almighty Witch," Maya Reane.

> [image: The Good Deeds of Old Adventurer Kane, chapter 1, page 19.]

In the first chapter, he manages to kill a giant black dragon with an incredibly lucky sword throw, which impresses Anastoria and Sephiria, while Maya sees it for the fluke that it was.

In chapter 8, he manages to save a little girl with a dark "evil god" form with a hug and his power of "kindness."

In chapter 10, he's attacked by a wartiger beastkin, one of the Demon Lord's eight generals, but she subsequently switches sides and pledges to follow his orders.